# OAuth not working with Age-gated Instagram Accounts

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I have a quick question concerning Age gated Instagram accounts.

Using our app, one of our customers wanted to add an account (https://www.instagram.com/jaegermeisterde/), which is age gated. The OAuth-process to grant permission to our Instagram app is not working. We do not get any information about why the OAuth-process is not working, it seems that the "CODE" parameter is not sent back to us.

Unfortunately, there is almost no information about Age gating available on the internets - and absolutely 0 about Age gating in regards to the Instagram API.
Does any of you have insights/information how to handle the case?

Thanks in advance!